# Getting first element from intersection java

Tags: java, hashset

I have two `HashSet`s:

```
a = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

and

```
b = [1,3,7,9]
```

I got their intersection by

```
b.retainAll(a);
```

But I want to get the intersection in the order of `a`, i.e I want the first element from the set `a` which occurs in set `b`. The current example should return 9.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If you *only* need the first element, then something like `for (Object oa : a) { if (b.contains(a)) return a; } return null;` should be sufficient. Otherwise, use LinkedHashSet as described by Juvanis in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21992968

Answer (score 2):

Use `LinkedHashSet` which keeps the order of elements. Then call `a.retainAll(b);`

Sample code:

```
Set<Integer> a = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>() {
    {
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            add(i);
        }
    }
};

Set<Integer> b = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>() {
    {
        add(1);
        add(3);
        add(7);
        add(9);
    }
};

a.retainAll(b);
```

After you execute the code above, the content of set `a` is as follows:

> [ 9, 7, 3, 1 ]

Comment: Not sure this completely addresses the OP's question: if he does b.retainAll(a), the order that is being preserved is the order of `b`, not of `a`. (Still, an ordered set is probably involved in the solution somehow..)

Comment: …so for example, after the call to retainAll(), the first element in b is 7, but you want 9. Maybe you could do something like `b.retainAll(a); a.retainAll(b);` and then grab the first element in `a`...

Comment: nice. I'm not sure (the OPs wording was unclear,) but I think he wants a way to find just the first element of set `a` after the intersection. You might want to show how that's done, since it's not obvious how to do that in a `Set`.  (I would probably go with getting an iterator and then returning null if hasNext() is false, and next() if it isn't, but it seems like there ought to be a tidier idiom for that...

Answer (score 1):

> I want the first element from the set a which occurs in set b. The
>   current example should return 9.

There is no order in `Set`, Use `ArrayList` or [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you need order.

LinkedHashSet :

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order.